# Solr search on specific field gives weird results

Tags: solr

Solr experts -

I have two records in my solr database:

```
  {
    "keywords":["jaime kelly jkelly natixis sales and marketing manager"],
    "job_role":"natixis sales & marketing manager",
    "empl_name":["jaime kelly jkelly"],
  },
  {
    "keywords":["schwayb jackson sjackson"],
    "job_role":"portfolio manager",
    "empl_name":["schwayb jackson sjackson"],
  }
```

When I search on the field empl_name with the query:

```
  empl_name:schwayb natixis
```

the first record returned is jaime kelly instead of schwayb jackson. This is weird. I am explicitly searching the field empl_name and among the two records the second one is the closer match. Why does Solr not order it correctly?

Looks like Solr sees the string "natixis" in the job_role and keywords of the earlier record and is giving it more preference. But I want solr to ONLY look at empl_name and no other field. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which query parser are you using? Is this the full query you're sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the query terms in parentheses. Or else it gets parsed as `empl_name:schwayb OR natixis`.

Comment: Thanks drjz! I was missing the parentheses. After adding them it produces the desired/expected results.